# How do I configure privileges for a Standard user account?

Tags: security, windows-xp, group-policy

How do I limit the features of a Standard user account, *without* affecting the Admin account?

Comment: What do you want to limit?  Is keeping the user's membership to only the Users group enough?  What else are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: are you running on a domain or just a workgroup??

Comment: workgroup .......

Answer (score 1):

You could put your Standard account users in their own OU and apply the GPO to that OU only

Answer (score 0):

You can use the policy editor to edit the privileges logged on users have (and a ton of other stuff),

type :

```
gpedit.msc
```

on the Win XP command line.

Comment: Yes but this takes effect for all accounts, unless I can figure out how to use snap-ins.